# All of my Jetbrain product has duplicate icon taskbar when running

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

[image]

All of my Jetbrain product has duplicate icon taskbar when running.

Look that phpstorm, i'm using windows 10, how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds similar: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143209